# I am accessing web service (.asmx) file in android programming

Tags: android

I am accessing  web service (.asmx) file in android programming. I am getting the following output:

```
anyType{CurrentPageIndex=0;TotalRows=0;RowsPerPage=0;Result=anyType{VGGlobalSearchResult=anyType{MerchantId=9090;MerchantName=Goodhue;Date=2014-01-06T23:17:15.837;Amount=50.000;InvoiceNo=12345;OrderNo=1;
ansactionId=8C57229c74f745f59c74f745f593d146A2c87B4210;AccountType=CC;FirstName=John;LastName=Jhon;Street=123 Main Street;DateFormatted=01/06/201423:17;};
}}}
```

How to access individual properties in android programming?

Comment: -1 What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have got data from WS, you just need to decode it to objects in Java.